# Why should we define improper convex function so?

Tags: convex-analysis

Now I'm reading Rockafellar's book. I don't understand why he defines improper convex function as $+\infty$ outside $\mbox{cl}(\mbox{dom} f)$. From page 54:

> [image: See page 54, corollary 7.2.2]

Why isn't it $-\infty$?

Comment: Why would it be $-\infty$?  Have you ever seen a convex function that tends toward $-\infty$ on both ends?

Comment: @Erick Wong, No, but I don't understand why can be +$\infty$ too? From Theorem 7.2 I understood that improper convex function must be infinite everywhere except boundary point of effective domain. But what about sign of $\infty$?

Comment: @ErickWong $f(x)=-\infty$ for all $x$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Exactly, there are no non-degenerate examples, thus there is little benefit in including them in the definition.

Comment: @conditionalMethod, can you explain me, please, why in definition Rockafellar uses +$\infty$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, ok, I add picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the only value you can use to preserve convexity everywhere outside the domain of $f$.

By the definition of convexity we know that $$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)y $$
for $x,y \in \mbox{dom}(f)$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$.  When we want to extend $f$ outside of its domain (this *looks* like we're assigning values to $f$ where it didn't have any previously, but actually we're finding a new function $f^*$ that coincides with $f$ on $\mbox{dom}(f)$ and has values elsewhere additionally) we still need to preserve the convexity relation.  That means 
$$f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)y $$
still needs to hold when $x\in \mbox{dom}(f)$ and $y\not\in \mbox{dom}(f)$ -- and the only way you can guarantee that is to make $f(y)$ bigger than any other number.

Comment: Thanks! But in the right part of the inequality I would write $\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$

Comment: @boris2018aa thanks for catching that!  I've edited it to be the way you write.